# Android Vertical layout is not setting up

Tags: android

Hi Guyies I am using a simple layout and creating it dynamically not in XML file.
I am adding buttons in it. So can anybody let me how to set the layout as vertical.
Tried a lot but not working at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh yes sure,

```
< LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
```

and for dynamic use this one : -

```
btn1.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
btn2.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: By the way I was only interested in Dynamic one and not on static. Anyways this works for me. And thanks for instant reply.

Comment: The first block was also for dynamic use.

Comment: Actually I am a beginner. So can you tell me how can we change it dynamic? since My use is for only once but dynamic.

Comment: Of course, if you want to change it dynamically but only once not more than that, then both the blocks are applicable. if you want to change the layout time to time then just place that code in a function and call it whenever needed.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for clearing out my mindset.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing more than this:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_layout);
layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

In your case, instead of finding the layout in `R`, use the one you created programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is call [`setOrientation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html#setOrientation%28int%29) on the `LinearLayout`. The default orientation is horizontal.

```
LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context);
layout.setOriantation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```